# How to install Spring4D

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I have downloaded the latest build of the Delphi Spring Framework.  As directed in the readme file, I ran Build.exe and selected my two versions of Delphi (XE5 and Seattle).  In neither Delphi installation can I see that a package has been installed nor my library search path modified.  What am I missing or is there something else I must do to install and use it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are no packages to install in Spring4D because only designtime packages are actually installed (as in they show up in the IDE). Everything the Build.exe does it compile the runtime packages for the selected Delphi versions and add the dcu folder to your library path (if you have checked that in the options).

The registry keys where it looks for the library path is specified in the Build.Settings.Compilers.ini (which are default values that every Delphi installation has).

Comment: Thanks.  I ran it again, this time with the "Update Delphi Registry" flag checked and was able to find the Spring4D folders had been added to the Library Path.

Comment: If you have Community Edition of Delphi, then you can build the packages only in the IDE , so Build.exe doesn't work. :( 
Could you explain what to do in this case?

Comment: It's explained in the README.md

Comment: Just to notice:  https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/src/master/

```
 open the project group in your IDE and compile the packages. Add the Library\<delphiversion>\<config> folder to your library path to access the precompiled units.
```